# reader only pulling one row in while loop C#

Tags: c#, fax

I have two problems.  One is that it is only pulling one row and sending it to ms fax when there are a few hundred to be sent.  The other is that it doesn't pull any more after that first and it throws an error.  I thought I was closing out my connections.  I don't understand what the problem is.  I have included the code and error.

Service1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Timers;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using FAXCOMLib;
using FAXCOMEXLib;

namespace ProcessFaxes
{
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public static Timer timer = new Timer();

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {

        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Tick);
        timer.Interval = 600000; // every 10 minutes
        timer.Enabled = true;
       // Console.ReadLine();
     }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {

    }

    public static void Tick(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        string connString = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=communications;Uid=root;password=pass;";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
        MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();

        MySqlConnection connupdate = new MySqlConnection(connString);
        MySqlCommand commandupdate = connupdate.CreateCommand();

        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM outbox WHERE `faxstat` = 'Y' AND `fax` <> '' AND `faxpro` = 'PENDING'";
        //command.CommandText = "UPDATE blah blah";
        //conn.Open();
        //conn.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //conn.Close();

        try
        {

            conn.Open();
            connupdate.Open();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Console.WriteLine(Ex.Message); 
                LogException(ex.ToString());

        throw;  // or whatever you want to do with it
        }
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(reader["filepath"].ToString());
                SendFax(reader["id"].ToString(), reader["filepath"].ToString(), @"C:\FAXDOC\" + reader["filepath"].ToString(), reader["account"].ToString(), reader["fax"].ToString(), reader["fax_orig"].ToString());
                string id = reader["id"].ToString();
                commandupdate.CommandText = "UPDATE outbox SET `faxpro` = 'DONE' WHERE `id` = '" + id + "'";
                commandupdate.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }

        conn.Close();
        connupdate.Close();
    }

    public static void SendFax(string DocumentId, string DocumentName, string FileName, string RecipientName, string FaxNumber, string RecipientHomePhone2)
    {
        if (FaxNumber != "")
        {
            try
            {
                FAXCOMLib.FaxServer faxServer = new FAXCOMLib.FaxServerClass();
                faxServer.Connect(Environment.MachineName);


                FAXCOMLib.FaxDoc faxDoc = (FAXCOMLib.FaxDoc)faxServer.CreateDocument(FileName);

                faxDoc.RecipientName = RecipientName;
                faxDoc.FaxNumber = FaxNumber;
                faxDoc.BillingCode = DocumentId;
                faxDoc.DisplayName = DocumentName;
                faxDoc.RecipientHomePhone = RecipientHomePhone2;

                int Response = faxDoc.Send();


                faxServer.Disconnect();

            }
            catch (Exception Ex) { 

               // Console.WriteLine(Ex.Message); 
                LogException(Ex.ToString());

        throw;  // or whatever you want to do with it
            }
        }



    }

    public static void LogException(string ErrorDescription)

    {

        // The name of our log in the event logs

        string Log = "Process Faxes";



        // Check to see fi the log for AspNetError exists on the machine

        //          If not, create it

        if ((!(EventLog.SourceExists(Log))))

        {


EventLog.CreateEventSource(Log, Log);

        }



        // Now insert your exception information into the AspNetError event log

        EventLog logEntry = new EventLog();

        logEntry.Source = Log;

        logEntry.WriteEntry(ErrorDescription, EventLogEntryType.Error);

        }


    }
}
```

error

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   Process Faxes
Event Category: None
Event ID:   0
Date:       3/6/2012
Time:       2:01:06 PM
User:       N/A
Computer:   FAXSERVER
Description:
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Too many connections
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at ProcessFaxes.Service1.Tick(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e) in C:\Documents and Settings\bruser\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ProcessFaxes\ProcessFaxes\Service1.cs:line 56
```

Comment: **warning** your code is susceptible to sql injection attacks!

Comment: You don't need two connections since they both connect to the same database.

Comment: Any reason you're using two separate connections? You really only need one. Also, if your code blows up after you open your connections, they won't get closed right away. You should move your working code into your `try`, and then close the connections in a `finally`. See my answer below.

Comment: How could my code be susceptible to injection when it is not accessible on the web?  I am only using it in-house on my fax server.

Comment: @RV-10Builder - Someone some way will hack it :).  I think he is pointing out a flaw that could endanger your program.  The point is not whether it is accessible or not.  You'd be surprised how many applications start small and end up running entire companies.  Note how he is warning you not forcing you, so take good advice and fix it before it becomes an issue.

Comment: Is it an issue with the connection information?  That is not the real user and password.  Or is an issue with putting my full code up?

Comment: @RV-10Builder the issue with the sql injection is you pass in `id` incorrectly to your update query. You should use a [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbys3e9s.aspx)

Comment: Did not see you where using MySql instead of MS Sql, here is the correct link for [MySqlParameter](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlparameter.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should refactor a bit. I explained a little in a comment above, but here's how I would change it (I added some comments for you too):

```
public static void Tick(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // Prevent another Tick from happening if this takes longer than 10 minutes
    (source as Timer).Enabled = false;

    // It would be better practice to put this in a settings or config file
    // so you can change it without having to recompile your application
    string connString = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=communications;Uid=root;password=pass;";

    // I won't change them here, but since these classes implement IDisposable,
    // you should be using a using statement around them:
    // using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connString))
    // {
    //     // use conn
    // }
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
    MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
    MySqlCommand updateCommand = conn.CreateCommand();

    command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM outbox WHERE `faxstat` = 'Y' AND `fax` <> '' AND `faxpro` = 'PENDING'";

    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                SendFax(reader["id"].ToString(), reader["filepath"].ToString(), @"C:\FAXDOC\" + reader["filepath"].ToString(), reader["account"].ToString(), reader["fax"].ToString(), reader["fax_orig"].ToString());
                string id = reader["id"].ToString();
                // I would use a prepared statement with either this query
                // or a stored procedure with parameters instead of manually
                // building this string (more good practice than worrying about
                // SQL injection as it's an internal app
                updateCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE outbox SET `faxpro` = 'DONE' WHERE `id` = '" + id + "'";
                updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogException(ex.ToString());
        throw;
    } 
    finally 
    {
        // If you're not going to use using-statements, you might want to explicitly
        // call dispose on your disposable objects:
        // command.Dispose();
        // updateCommand.Dispose();
        conn.Close();
        // conn.Dispose();
    }

    // Enable the timer again
    (source as Timer).Enabled = true;
}
```

As to why you're only receiving one row when you're expecting many, I suspect your SQL is at fault.

Comment: I'd wrap these statements in `using` blocks and that will help manage the resources.

Comment: If I use the "using" for idisposable.. Do I end the brackets after the finally brackets or do I only put the mysql commands within the "using" section that is now commented out above?  Will the using section cover the entire area or will it just be the little section at the top?

Comment: @RV-10Builder: The `using` in the comment above was just an example of its usage. I would start the `using` sort of where it is, and end it after the `catch` -- you won't need the `finally` because the `Dispose()` methods will clean up the connection for you.

Comment: Event Type: Error
Event Source: Process Faxes
Event Category: None
Event ID: 0
Date:  3/7/2012
Time:  9:55:50 AM
User:  N/A
Computer: FAXSERVER
Description:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070102): The wait operation timed out. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070102)
   at FAXCOMLib.IFaxDoc.Send()
   at ProcessFaxes.Service1.SendFax(String DocumentId, String DocumentName, String FileName, String RecipientName, String FaxNumber, String RecipientHomePhone2) in C:\Documents and Settings\bruser\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ProcessFaxes\ProcessFaxes\Service1.cs:line 118

Comment: @RV-10Builder: Could be permissions. Whatever it is it sounds like the COM library the faxing service uses is saying it tried to send a fax but took too long. Whatever it is probably isn't your code -- you'll have to consult with whoever built the FAXCOM interop library.

Comment: It only pulled one row again.  Here is the error.  MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.CheckState()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at ProcessFaxes.Service1.Tick(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e) in C:\Documents and Settings\bruser\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ProcessFaxes\ProcessFaxes\Service1.cs:line 76

Comment: @RV-10Builder: Then you probably need to close the reader after you're done using it by calling `reader.Close()`, or use instead `using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) { if (reader.HasRows) { ... } }`

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using a timer.

A timer fires at regular intervals, and does not care if the previous event has completed or not.

Look at using a [Background Worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to send your faxes, having it loop over the queue, and then pause when the queue is empty.

Comment: ... or you can disable the timer while `Tick` is executing.

Comment: @AustinSalonen: Have you had any problems with that?  I used to do that, but after a random number of iterations, the timer_tick event would no longer fire after starting the timer.  I never bothered to track the issue down, though.

Comment: I guess I should have spent some time tracking it down.  It was a known bug that was fixed years ago.  :)  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/842793

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in your connection object.  You have defined a couple of connection objects.  You only need one.

Here are the two in question:

`MySqlConnection connupdate = new MySqlConnection(connString);`

`MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);`

Eliminate the connection to one of them.

Here is one way to fix your code:

```
string connString = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=communications;Uid=root;password=pass;";

using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySQLConnection(connString))
   {
   using(MySQlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
     {
      command.CommandText = "SELECT ...";
      conn.Open();
      using(MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
           {
             //process rows...
           }
     }
   }
```

Comment: So, change  MySqlCommand commandupdate = connupdate.CreateCommand(); to  MySqlCommand commandupdate = conn.CreateCommand(); in order to use the same connection ??  And do away with     MySqlConnection connupdate = new MySqlConnection(connString);

Comment: You just need to manage one connection object.  You have defined two objects to manage one database connection - the point is you don't need two objects for this.  See my edit.

Comment: He will still need two connections as he is doing a update before the reader has finished processing, you can not use the connection until the reader has been closed. See the [Remarks section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx#remarksToggle) of the SqlDataReader page

Comment: @ScottChamberlain:  While you might be right, the link provided is not correct here.  MySql != MS SQL

Comment: Oops, misread MySql vs Sql. However, [my information is still correct](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqldatareader.html) (2nd paragraph).